# crudrepository findBy method signature with multiple in operators?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity Class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMAIL")
class Email{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    Long id;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
    String emailId;
    @Column(name = "PIN_CODE")
    String pincode;
}
```

How to write `findBy` method for the below query using crudrepository spring data jpa?

```
select email_id,name from email_details where eamil_id in('mike@gmail.com','ram@gmail.com') and pin_code in('633677','733877')
```

I am expecting the spring data jpa method like the below but how to construct it?

```
List<Email> findBy.....(List<String> emails, List<String> pinCodes);
```

I want to get list of Emails in a single database hit.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

The following signature will do:

```
List<Email> findByEmailIdInAndPincodeIn(List<String> emails, List<String> pinCodes);
```

Spring Data JPA supports a large number of keywords to build a query. [`IN` and `AND` are among them](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).