# Is there a way to query from method names with a list of parameters in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am building an application in Spring Boot. I have a repository and I am creating queries from method names in the following way:

```
public interface Example extends Repository {

     User findUserByName(String name);

}
```

Such a query works, and the result of the method call is a User with that name. 
Is it possible in Spring Boot to create a query by name, where the input is a list of names and the output is a list of users where each user corresponds to at least a name in the list? For example something like:

```
      List<User> findAllUserByName(List<String> name)
```

I have tried such a method, but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32796493/6553042 check this out, it might be duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below:

```
List<User> findByUserIn(List<String> nameList);
```

Ref:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords