# Exception org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**I'm not able to run my application** Spring Boot JPA Spring Data Service Rest

*Client Class include in bnp.bmci.entities package*

```
 @Entity 
public class Client implements Serializable{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codeClient;
    private String nomClient;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    private Collection<Compte> comptes;

    public Long getCodeClient() {
        return codeClient;
    }

    public void setCodeClient(Long codeClient) {
        this.codeClient = codeClient;
    }
    public String getNomClient() {
        return nomClient;
    }
    public void setNomClient(String nomClient) {
        this.nomClient = nomClient;
    }
    public Collection<Compte> getComptes() {
        return comptes;
    }
    public void setComptes(Collection<Compte> comptes) {
        this.comptes = comptes;
    }
    public Client() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Client(Long codeClient, String nomClient, Collection<Compte> comptes) {
        super();
        this.codeClient = codeClient;
        this.nomClient = nomClient;
        this.comptes = comptes;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client [codeClient=" + codeClient + ", nomClient=" + nomClient + ", comptes=" + comptes + "]";
    }

    public Client(Long codeClient, String nomClient) {
        super();
        this.codeClient = codeClient;
        this.nomClient = nomClient;
    }

}
```

*Repository include in  bnp.bmci.dao package*

```
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>{

}
```

*ClientMetier interface*

```
 package bnp.bmci.metier;

import java.util.List;
import bnp.bmci.entities.Client;

public interface ClientMetier {
    public Client saveClient(Client c);
    public List<Client> listClient();

}
```

*ClientMetierImpl class*

```
package bnp.bmci.metier;
@Service
public class ClientMetierImpl implements ClientMetier{

        @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;
    @Override
    public Client saveClient(Client c) {
        return clientRepository.save(c);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Client> listClient() {
        return clientRepository.findAll();
    }   

}
```

*And finally ClientRestService in bnp.bmci.service package*

```
@RestController
public class ClientRestService {
    @Autowired
    private ClientMetier clientMetier;

    @RequestMapping(value="/clients", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Client saveClient(@RequestBody Client c) {
        return clientMetier.saveClient(c);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/clients", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Client> listClient() {
        return clientMetier.listClient();
    }

}
```

*I can't fixe a Spring "unsatisfied dependency" error message*
Below is the error which I am getting

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-11-14 22:11:46.472 ERROR 9496 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientMetierImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Client!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at bnp.bmci.BanqueApplication.main(BanqueApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Client!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Client!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.derived.DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery.<init>(DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery.java:47) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryMethod.createQuery(GraphQueryMethod.java:95) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(GraphQueryLookupStrategy.java:45) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.java:43) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception

Comment: Do you have @Repository annotation for your ClientRepository ?

Comment: I don't have @Repository in ClientRepository

Answer (score 2):

Your ClientRepository should have @Repository and you should have enabled

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy"})` in your configuration

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have missed to mark `@Repository` for your class:

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>{

}
```