# How to write dynamic native SQL Query in spring data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to write a search query on multiple tables in database in spring boot web application.

It uses spring data jpa. I know we can write native query in spring data jpa using @Query annotation and native = true flag.

Is there any way I can write query in repository class and instead of the @Query annotation as the Query is very complex and dynamic.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses/38576851

Answer (score 11):

You need to do a `CustomRepository` and add a method with native query.

I do that this way:

1. Create your custom repository:

   ```
   public interface OcorrenciaRepositoryCustom {
      List<Object[]> getStrings(List<String> valores);
   }
   ```
2. Implement your custom repository:
   (The name of the implemantation must be the name of original repository add Impl as suffix.)

   ```
   public class OcorrenciaRepositoryImpl implements OcorrenciaRepositoryCustom {
       @PersistenceContext
       private EntityManager entityManager;

       @Override
       public List<Object[]> getStrings(List<String> strings) {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.append("SELECT count(o.id) FROM soebm.ocorrencia o WHERE 1=1 ");

           if(strings.get(0)!=null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(strings.get(0))) {
               sb.append(" AND to_char(o.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= :dataInicio ");
           }

           Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sb.toString());

           if(strings.get(0)!=null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(strings.get(0).toString())) {
               query.setParameter("dataInicio", strings.get(0));
           }
           return query.getResultList();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Extend your custom repository from main repository:

   ```
   public interface OcorrenciaRepository extends JpaRepository<Ocorrencia, Long>, OcorrenciaRepositoryCustom {
       Ocorrencia findByPosto(Posto posto);
   }
   ```
4. Now, in the service, you can call your new method from the main repository.

   ```
   @Autowired
   private OcorrenciaRepository repository;

   public List<Object[]> findOcorrenciaCustom(String str) {
       List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>() {{add(dataInicio);}};
       return repository.getStrings(strings);
   }
   ```

It is important that the custom repository is under the package searched by JpaRepositories

`@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.my.repository")`

I used Spring-Data-Jpa 1.9 in this example. It worked perfectly in my project.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List OcorrenciaRepositoryCustom.getStrings(java.lang.String)! No property getStrings found for type Ocorrencia.
What is missing in Ocorrencia entity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception