# How to pick a subset of fields with JPA specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using jdk 1.8. I am using **JPA specification** to pull up the records where each object is **heavy weight** and with large number of such object is leading to memory-out-of-space error/exception (**heap exhausted**). **This whole path is working fine when there are only couple of hundred records.** And that is the reason that I am looking for a way to pull up only **a couple of fields** ( instead of whole object ) with jpa-specification-query. And latter, we will pull up whole records as necessary where applicable.  Here is the glimpse of my code :

This an **example object**(which is an hibernate entity):

```
public class Referral {
 
   long id;
   Date createdDate;

   B anotherObject1;
   C anotherObject2;

   ..... etc
}
```

Now the **specification** is created using the fields in **object of B** and **object of C**. For example :

```
public Specification<ClinAssistReferral> getSpecification(Contact currentContact) {
    return (itemRoot, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
      
        List<Predicate> finalQueries = new ArrayList<>();
        finalQueries.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("anotherObject1").get("field1"), currentContact.getId()));
        finalQueries.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("anotherObject2").get("field5"), currentContact.getJeta()));

        return   criteriaBuilder.and(finalQueries.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

**Then  pulling up records this way:**

```
Specification< Referral > spec = getSpecification(currentContact);
List<Referral> refs = repository.findAll(spec, pageable);
```

Where repository  has it's findAll method :

```
@Override
@NonNull
List<Referral> findAll(@Param("spec") Specification<Referral> spec);
```

For information, I can not use pagination here directly ( that could have resolved our issue ) for some reasons. Instead of pulling up the whole object (which is much heavier than my example object), I am just trying to pull up **id** and **createdDate.**

**Is there a way to pull up object with sublist of fields when have to use other fields in specification?**

I tried by changing the specification creation method by addiing :

```
return (itemRoot, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        List<Selection<?>> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();
        selectionList.add(itemRoot.get("id"));
        selectionList.add(itemRoot.get("createdDate"));
        query.multiselect(selectionList);

        List<Predicate> finalQueries = new ArrayList<>();
        finalQueries.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("anotherObject1").get("field1"), currentContact.getId()));
        finalQueries.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("anotherObject2").get("field5"), currentContact.getJeta()));

        return   criteriaBuilder.and(finalQueries.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

It did not help.Seems it pulls up the whole objects still.Or **may be I am not using the query.multiSelect** in the right way. Can I get help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get only selected columns from DB with multiple filtering criteria spring boot 2 JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64312184/5221149)

Comment: I am using specification, predicate etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pull up object with sublist of fields when have to use other fields in specification?

apparently not yet. as you can read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049307/12854146

if you want you could use Criteria jpa to achieve what you need

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
private static class ReferralDTO {
    private Long id;
    private Date createdDate;
}

private List<ReferralDTO> findAllByCurrentContact(Contact currentContact) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ReferralDTO> criteria = builder.createQuery(ReferralDTO.class);
    Root<Referral> referral = criteria.from(Referral.class);

    //projection
    criteria.select(builder.construct(ReferralDTO.class, referral.get("id"), referral.get("createdDate")));

    //where
    criteria.where(
            builder.equal(referral.get("anotherObject1").get("field1"), currentContact.getId()),
            builder.equal(referral.get("anotherObject2").get("field5"), currentContact.getJeta()));
    
    //if you need sorting invoke criteria.orderBy()

    TypedQuery<ReferralDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
    //if you need pagination invoke query.setFirstResult and query.setMaxResults

    return query.getResultList();
}
```