# Stackoverflow error while getting data using spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I get error getting data from database:

**Error:**

```
2017-02-16 23:53:36.748  INFO 7420 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-02-16 23:53:37.015 ERROR 7420 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByTopicId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:478) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByTopicId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:478) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByTopicId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:478) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByTopicId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:478) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByTopicId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:478) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByTopicId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:478) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByTopicId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:478) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class TopicBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "userImage")
    private String userImage;
    @Column(name = "dayPosted")
    private String dayPosted;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Component
public class TopicRepositoryImpl implements TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    @Override
    public TopicBean findByTopicId(String id) {
         return topicRepository.findByTopicId(id);
    }

    Page<TopicBean> findAllByPage(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Service:

```
TopicBean findById(long id);

List<TopicBean> findByUsername(String name);

List<TopicBean> findTop10ByUsername(String name);

void saveTopic(TopicBean topicBean);

void updateTopic(TopicBean topicBean);

TopicBean findByTopicId(String id);

void deleteTopicById(long id);

Long deleteByTopicId(String id);

Page<TopicBean> findAllByPage(Pageable pageable); 

void deleteAllTopics();

public boolean isTopicExist(TopicBean topicBean);
```

Service Impl:

```
@Component
public class TopicRepositoryImpl implements TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    @Override
    public TopicBean findByTopicId(String id) {
         return topicRepository.findByTopicId(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<TopicBean> findAllByPage(Pageable pageable) {
        return topicRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

If I am not wrong, I am getting this error after I changed the class name of `TopicServiceImpl` to `TopicRepositoryImpl`

I had to change the name of class because of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception/30139286#30139286)

So how do I resolve this?

Comment: Your ID should be a `Long`, not a `String`. (And you can discard your entire `TopicRepositoryImpl` and `TopicService` if that's all they're doing. With `DomainClassConverter`, you can even just say `@PathVariable TopicBean beanId` and Spring will do all of this for you.)

Comment: @chrylis there are other similar service impl in that service class which I didn't include.

Comment: @chrylis updated the service class. I am using custom ID(topic Id) in the table in database along with normal ID. The issue could be with ID not being Long?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a StackOverflowException because you have an infinite loop in your code. Notice that the following is repeating:

```
at seconds47.serviceImpl.TopicRepositoryImpl.findByTopicId(TopicRepositoryImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
```

Your code seems a little unclear as it seems you have updated the code, but not on here. It seems your TopicService interface extends TopicRepository, thus this service is referencing itself.

Answer (score 1):

This method in `TopicRepositoryImpl` calls itself, causing the stackoverflow.

```
@Override
public TopicBean findByTopicId(String id) {
     return topicRepository.findByTopicId(id);
}
```

As *Donny* hinted at you can find such code by looking at the repeated part of the stack trace and look for frames coming from your code.