# Spring Data 1.11.7 No property existsBy

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Good morning!

My Spring application doesn't seem to detect existsBy projections

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property existsById found for type Planet!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
```

Code in the repository

`public boolean existsByIdAndOwnerId(Long planetId, Integer ownerId);`

- Spring version: 4.3.12.RELEASE
- Hibernate version: 5.2.12.Final
- Spring Data JPA version: 1.11.7.RELEASE

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539097/8906016 check it

Comment: you need to use findBy instead of exist by (i.e `public boolean findByIdAndOwnerId(Long planetId, Integer ownerId);`).

Answer (score 1):

Try naming the method:  `existsPlanetByIdAndOwnerId()`

This link may help:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending `CrudRepository<T, ID>` in your repository it provides `existById(ID)` which takes id as parameter and returns Boolean based on db entry's existence. For your case you can do like this: `public boolean findByIdAndOwnerId(Long planetId, Integer ownerId);`

Comment: This code doesn't work, returns the following error: "Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type". You'll need to make a wrapper method that will return "false" if it detects a null value from the "findById.." method (which should return an object of that type, not a boolean).