# org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property count found for type Employee! in Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I already went through urls like [Spring Data JPA - "No Property Found for Type" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception), but it did not solved my issue yet. I'm developing `Spring Boot + Spring Data Redids` example. In this example, I am contineously facing the below issues. I have used  `QueryByExampleExecutor<Employee>` as suggested in https://programtalk.com/vs/?source=spring-data-examples/jpa/query-by-example/src/test/java/example/springdata/jpa/querybyexample/UserRepositoryInheritanceIntegrationTests.java

Here is the source code for reference: https://github.com/JavaHelper/spring-redis-examples/tree/master/redis-example

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property count found for type Employee!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:334)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:269)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.createQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.prepareQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.execute(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:602)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, String>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Employee>{

}
```

Employee.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id @Indexed
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    private List<Department> departments;
}
```

Test class/Main Method

```
Example<Employee> example = Example.of(new Employee(null, "Raj", null, null, null));
long count = employeeRepository.count(example);
System.out.println("COUNT_OF_EMPLOYEE = "+count);
```

Any Quick pointers??