# Error "PropertyReferenceException: No property exists found for type" when adding QueryByExampleExecutor to repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

When adding the QueryByExampleExecutor, im getting the following error:

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property exists found for type Artifact!

```java
public interface ArtifactRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Artifact, UUID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Artifact>
```

Using the following Spring Boot version:

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
```

With the spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j dependency

Repository

```java
public interface ArtifactRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Artifact, UUID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Artifact> {

    Optional<Artifact> findGroupIdAndByArtifactIdAndVersion(String groupId, String artifactId, String version);

    List<Artifact> findByGroupIdAndArtifactId(String groupId, String artifactId);

}
```

Artifact

```java
@NodeEntity
@CompositeIndex(properties = { "groupId", "artifactId", "version" })
public class Artifact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    private UUID id;

    private String groupId;
    private String artifactId;
    private String version;

    public Artifact() {
    }

    public Artifact(final String groupId, final String artifactId, final String version) {
        this();
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.artifactId = artifactId;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
...
```

Getting the following stack error:
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property exists found for type Artifact!

Thanks for the help

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception)

Comment: I took a deeper look and the property 'exists' is from the QueryByExampleExecutor which is spring data stuff. Just removing that part of the extends and the error is gone. So it seems linked directly to the use of that class and not a naming convention like it the suggested issue.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Nope ... I removed the use of QueyByExample and have not revisited since.