# How to make a Restful API to handle many-to-many relation in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring boot project, I have two tables names- **doctors** and **patients**. In these tables, I have following attributes-

[image]

[image]

Now, the thing is I want to create a **many to many relation** between these two tables for **appointment** as one doctor can have many patients and one patient can have appointment of multiple doctors. So, to handle this problem, I have created another table named appointment which will have **doctorId and patientId as foreign key**.

I need to create appointment by using JSON request body like below-

[image]

So, for this purpose I have created a **model** class like below-

**Appointment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appointments")
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Long appointedDoctorId;

    @NotNull
    private Long appointedPatientId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctorId", nullable = false)
    private Doctor doctor;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patientId", nullable = false)
    private Patient patient;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Long getAppointedDoctorId() {
        return appointedDoctorId;
    }

    public void setAppointedDoctorId(Long appointedDoctorId) {
        this.appointedDoctorId = appointedDoctorId;
    }

    public Long getAppointedPatientId() {
        return appointedPatientId;
    }

    public void setAppointedPatientId(Long appointedPatientId) {
        this.appointedPatientId = appointedPatientId;
    }

    public Doctor getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }
}
```

Here's the **Repository** class-

**AppointmentRepository .java**

```
@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long> {

    Page<Appointment> findByDoctorId(Long id, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Here's my **Service** interface-

**AppointmentService .java**

```
public interface AppointmentService {

    public Page<Appointment> getAllAppointmentByDoctorId(@PathVariable(value = "doctorId") Long id, Pageable pageable);

    public Appointment createAppointment(@Valid @RequestBody Appointment createAppointmentRequest);

}
```

Here's the implementation of my Service class-

**AppointmentServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class AppointmentServiceImpl implements AppointmentService {

    @Autowired
    AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;


    @Override
    public Page<Appointment> getAllAppointmentByDoctorId(Long id, Pageable pageable) {
        return appointmentRepository.findByDoctorId(id, pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public Appointment createAppointment(@Valid Appointment createAppointmentRequest) {
        return appointmentRepository.save(createAppointmentRequest);
    }
}
```

And at last I have this **Controller** class-

**Appointment.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AppointmentController {

    @Autowired
    AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @GetMapping("/doctors/{doctorId}/appointments")
    public Page<Appointment> getAllAppointmentsByDoctorId(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Pageable pageable){
        return appointmentService.getAllAppointmentByDoctorId(id, pageable);
    }


    @PostMapping("/insert/new/appointments")
    public Appointment createAppointment(@Valid Appointment createAppointmentRequest) {
        return appointmentService.createAppointment(createAppointmentRequest);
    }

}
```

But whenever I run the project and do POST request for creating the Appointment using the mentioned request body, it is showing the following response-

[image]

So, I need to know what's the problem in my code and how can I create an appointment **POST request** by giving the **doctorId** and **patientId** like the way I mentioned in JSON RequestBody **request.**

Comment: Looks like the issue you have has been answered here [No property found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception)

Comment: Can you check is your column name is `doctorId` or `doctor_id` in appointment table ?

Comment: The question has been updated, please check.