# REST API: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am building a REST API and can't seem to get rid of the org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException, I can't spot the issue in this. I will appreciate a fresh insight into this.

p.s: Using mongo DB for this

first off the full error

```
2020-05-04 01:16:31.468  WARN 14412 
--- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - 
cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'productController': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'productServiceImpl':
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepo'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'productRepo': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException:
 No property id found for type Product!
```

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    private int ProductId;

// and other variables plus setters and getters
```

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepo extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

   // methods
}
```

```
public interface ProductService {
 // methods
}
```

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepo productRepo;

// implementations
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA - "No Property Found for Type" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `Product` class as the following:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String productId; // MongoRepository<Product, String>

    // methods
}
```

In the `Product` class the `@Entity` annotation is missing and the `productId` should be a `String`, as specified in the repository.

Or change to `extends MongoRepository<Product, Integer>` if you want to keep the current field type.

In any case, they should match.

Answer (score 0):

Make You That Your Spring Application Knows Where Your Classes Resides.
Use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.package")`.

Moreover If Your Product Class Is Something That You Want to Persist Mark It With `@Entity` So Spring Knows about It And Creates A Bean Out Of it.

Mark Your interface ProductService with `@service`, So that Spring Knows About it.

Answer (score 0):

Unsatisfieddependencyexception:
Repository.java this page like @respository annotation class below being return type null and near optinal <> using default keyword
This method working me.