# How to show a list of skills sorted by their number of likes in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf with Pageable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to get a list of skills sorted by their number of likes in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf with Pageable but I´m bumping into problems. I´m not sure how to do this. What would be a good way to approach this problem?

Edit. Error: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'skillRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'skillRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List projekti.Skill.SkillRepository.findAllSkills(projekti.Account.Account,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property findAllSkills found for type Skill!

AccountController.java

```
@GetMapping("/profile/{path}")
public String profile(Model model, @PathVariable String path) {
     Account account = accountRepository.findByPath(path);
     Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by("likes").descending());
     model.addAttribute("skills", skillRepository.findAllSkills(account, pageable));

     return "profile";
}
```

Skill.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Skill extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="who_liked",
        joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="skill_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="like_account_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Account> likes = new ArrayList<>();  
}
```

SkillRepository.java

```
public interface SkillRepository extends JpaRepository<Skill, Long> {
    List<Skill> findAllSkills(Account account, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Profile.html

```
<li th:each="skill : ${skills}">
      <span th:text="${skill.name}">skill</span>
      <form th:action="@{/profile/{path}/skill/{id}/like(path=${path}, id=${skill.id})}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="skillLike" name="skillLike" value="skillLike"/>
            <button type="submit"><span th:text="${#lists.size(skill.likes)}">likes</span></button> 
            <span> likes</span>                 
     </form>
</li>
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: I'm getting the error: "No property findAllSkills found for type Skill!". Added the full error message in the post.

Comment: seem to me that no skill property in skill class? Shouldn't the method name findAll?

Comment: This gives me the error: "No property findAll found for type Skill!".

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception)

Answer (score 0):

`findAllSkills` not exist in interface `JpaRepository`, you can change it to `findAll`

Comment: This gives me the error: "No property findAll found for type Skill!".