# JAVA: Error creating bean with name; Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code and structure. I am getting the following error, it is very long error message.

> Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'departmentService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Entity Class

```
package com.example.departmentservice.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long departmentId;
    private String departmentName;
    private String departmentAddress;
    private String departmentCode;
}
```

Repository Interface

```
package com.example.departmentservice.repository;

import com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {
    Department findDepartmentById(Long departmentId);
}
```

Service  Class

```
package com.example.departmentservice.service;

import com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department;
import com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class DepartmentService {
    @Autowired
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    public Department saveDepartment(Department department) {
        log.info("Inside saveDepartment of department service");
        return departmentRepository.save(department);
    }

    public Department findDepartmentById(Long departmentId) {
        log.info("Inside findDepartmentById of department service");
        return departmentRepository.findDepartmentById(departmentId);
    }
}
```

Controller Class

```
package com.example.departmentservice.controller;

import com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department;
import com.example.departmentservice.service.DepartmentService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/departments")
@Slf4j
public class DepartmentController {
    @Autowired
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Department saveDepartment(@RequestBody Department department) {
        log.info("Inside saveDepartment of department controller");
        return departmentService.saveDepartment(department);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Department findDepartmentById(@PathVariable("id") Long departmentId) {
        log.info("Inside findDepartmentById of department controller");
        return departmentService.findDepartmentById(departmentId);
    }
}
```

Main class

```
package com.example.departmentservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DepartmentServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DepartmentServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Project Structure

```
src
  main
    java
      com.example.departmentservice
        controller
        entity
        repository
        service
```

Full Error Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentRepository' defined in com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.example.departmentservice.DepartmentServiceApplication.main(DepartmentServiceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentRepository' defined in com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentRepository' defined in com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1051) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.departmentservice.entity.Department com.example.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository.findDepartmentById(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type Department!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Department!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Comment: And your `@SpringBootApplication` class please? Also please post the packages of your classes maybe the missing clue is there.

Comment: @pleft added the SpringBootApplication and also the packages, please check.

Comment: Hmm I think you should post the whole error stacktrace and not just those 3 lines...Do you have any class annotated `@Configuration` by the way? Make sure you post its code also

Comment: I'd recommend you to autowire beans in constructors, not only it's a better practice, but it will help you debug better.

Comment: @SebastianAguerre what do you mean by Autowire beans in constrcture.

Comment: @pleft i added the full error stack trace.

Comment: @user2281858 See this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual error is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Department!
```

Your repository method:

```
Department findDepartmentById(Long departmentId);
```

But you dont have `id` property in your `Department` entity. You have `departmentId`. So try renaming your method to something like:

```
Department findByDepartmentId(Long departmentId);
```

Comment: This, see the following link where something similar was asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception

Comment: @pleft did not understand the answer, what should i rename what to?

Comment: The method name :) from findDepartment**By**Id to find**By**DepartmentId

Comment: @pleft jesus really, i am sorry i am new to Java, hard to believe that was the issue.

Comment: @user2281858 The method name specifies the query, so you had `...ById` and unfortunatelly your Entity doesn't have `id` property but `departmentId`. So you needed to write the method name a bit more carefully. Good luck to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `department_id` try to use id in `Department` entity.