# The function findall(Sorty.by("created_at").descending()) not able to read the property

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to get list of data sorted by a property "created_at" by using the following method. But the Sort.by() method is not able to read the property name , it is only reading "created" not "created_at".

```
    public List<Invoice> getAllInvoices() {
    return repo.findAll(Sort.by("created_at").descending());    
}
```

Below is the console message:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property created found for type Invoice!
```

[image]

Comment: In the class Invoice ,the property is named "createdAt" or "created_at" ?

Comment: @OussamaZAGHDOUD its created_at .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the issue in your case as well:
I ran into this same issue and found the solution here: https://dzone.com/articles/persistence-layer-spring-data

I had renamed an entity property. But with Springs Automatic Custom Queries there was an interface defined for the old property name.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539097/10832295