# Error creating bean with name 'taxeIRImpl'

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I try to run my project I get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taxeIRImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'taxeIRDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taxeIRDao' defined in com.example.taxe.dao.TaxeIRDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.taxe.bean.TaxeIR com.example.taxe.dao.TaxeIRDao.findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(int,int,com.example.taxe.bean.Employe)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.taxe.bean.TaxeIR com.example.taxe.dao.TaxeIRDao.findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(int,int,com.example.taxe.bean.Employe)! No property findbyMois found for type TaxeIR!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.taxe.bean.TaxeIR com.example.taxe.dao.TaxeIRDao.findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(int,int,com.example.taxe.bean.Employe)! No property findbyMois found for type TaxeIR!   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]   at com.example.taxe.ProjetTaxeIrApplication.main(ProjetTaxeIrApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

Here are my beans :

```
@Entity
public class TaxeIR {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private int mois;
    private int annee;
    @ManyToOne
    private Employe employe;
    @ManyToOne
    private Employeur employeur;
    private double salaire;
    private double cotisation;
    private String employeICE;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
```

```
@Entity
public class Employe {
    @Id @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String cin;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private double salaire;
    @ManyToOne
    private Employeur employeur;
```

```
@Repository
public interface TaxeIRDao extends JpaRepository<TaxeIR, Long> {
    TaxeIR findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(int mois,int annee,Employe employe);
    List<TaxeIR> findByEmployeCin(String cin);
    List<TaxeIR> findByUserLogin(String login);
    List<TaxeIR> findByEmployeICE(String rc);
}
```

```
@Service
public class TaxeIRImpl implements TaxeIRService {
    @Autowired
    TaxeIRDao taxeIRDao;

    @Override
    public List<TaxeIR> findByEmployeCin(String cin) {
        return findByEmployeCin(cin);}

    @Override
    public List<TaxeIR> findByUserLogin(String login) {
        return findByUserLogin(login);}

    @Override
    public TaxeIR findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(int mois, int annee, Employe employe) {
        return findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(mois,annee,employe);}

    @Override
    public List<TaxeIR> findByEmployeICE(String rc) {
        return taxeIRDao.findByEmployeICE(rc);}
    @Override
    public int save(TaxeIR taxeIR) {
        TaxeIR taxeIRfound = findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(taxeIR.getMois(),taxeIR.getAnnee(),taxeIR.getEmploye());
        if(taxeIRfound!=null)
            return -1;
        else {
            taxeIRDao.save(taxeIR);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/taxeIR")
public class TaxeIRWs {
    @Autowired
    private TaxeIRImpl taxeIRImpl;
    @GetMapping("/cin/{cin}")
    public List<TaxeIR> findByEmployeCin(@PathVariable String cin) {
        return taxeIRImpl.findByEmployeCin(cin);
    }
    @GetMapping("/login/{login}")
    public List<TaxeIR> findByUserLogin(@PathVariable String login) {
        return taxeIRImpl.findByUserLogin(login);
    }
    @GetMapping("/mois/{mois}/annee/{annee}")
    public TaxeIR findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(@PathVariable int mois,@PathVariable int annee,@RequestBody  Employe employe) {
        return taxeIRImpl.findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(mois, annee, employe);
    }

    @GetMapping("/rc/{rc}")
    public List<TaxeIR> findByEmployeICE(@PathVariable String rc) {
        return taxeIRImpl.findByEmployeICE(rc);
    }
    @PostMapping("/")
    public int save(@RequestBody TaxeIR TaxeIR) {
        return taxeIRImpl.save(TaxeIR);
    }
}
```

I reviewed all my files and I can't seem to find the error myself, like I said in the title I am a beginner and I would like some help.

The expected result is for it to just run and for me to be able to interact with it through Postman

Comment: Your field is named `annee` not `anne` as you have written in your `findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum I seriously could not even read the code that fast

Comment: Also it should most likely be `findByMois...` and not `findbyMois...` (note the capital B).

Comment: The reason for the error is in the error message itself. Unfortunately, the way you pasted it makes it very difficult to find. Please paste properly formatted messages next time. The cause of the problem in this instance is: "No property findbyMois found for type TaxeIR"

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am correcting thoses mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a silly little mistake, but the devil's in de detail.

You need to use CamelCasing for this method:

```
TaxeIR findbyMoisAndAnneAndEmploye(int mois,int annee,Employe employe);
```

You have 'findby' and it needs to be 'findBy'. Capital B.

See this answer if you want further details:
[Spring Data JPA - "No Property Found for Type" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583540/spring-data-jpa-no-property-found-for-type-exception)